# Implement Material Design CrossFadeDrawer

Tags: android, material-design, materialdrawer

I am trying to implement CrossFadeDraweLayout using https://github.com/mikepenz/CrossfadeDrawerLayout which is basically a subpart of the project under the name Material Drawer available on GitHub.

I have gone through all the code provided and I am not able to import the following libraries

```
com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader;
com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeaderBuilder;
com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils;
```

Also can anyone explain the point of the custom library that he has added in his app for CrossfadeDrawerlayout

Answer (score 0):

The `CrossfadeDrawerLayout` is a stand alone library which provides a `DrawerLayout` with a `Crossfade` effect.

To provide a great example the sample app uses the `MaterialDrawer` library to provide the normal full drawer view, and the mini drawer view.

If you need a drawer in your project I highly recommend to also use the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Just add the `gradle` dependency and you are fine.

In the case you don't need a `Drawer` which contains items, and have your own views, you can just drop out the references and use the `CrossfadeDrawerLayout` as you would do with a normal `DrawerLayout`

You can then just get the reference to the `CrossfadeDrawerLayout` as you would normally do:

```
CrossfadeDrawerLayout drawer = (CrossfadeDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.crossfadeDrawer);
```

And after this use the `CrossfadeDrawerLayout` specific APIs to modify it

```
//set the max width (1000 is just a sample number)
drawer.setMaxWidthPx(1000);

//add the small view
drawer.getSmallView().addView(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```